# Assessing significant differnces between groups of data that are spatially correlated

Tags: autocorrelation, spatial, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I'm working with data from a lattice, that is squares located in a two-dimensional structure.

I want to test whether groups of squares (which then are spatially correlated) have significant differences for a response variable.

I'm using the pairwise wilcoxon test, however, as I mentioned above, the squares within each group are not indipendents but they are spatially correlated. Wilcoxon test can be used? Or is it better to use another test?

Comment: These situations can be subtle and complex.  For instance, how do you identify these groups of squares?  Have they been established *a priori* or are you creating them from data? If the latter, is their creation independent of the response or not? How is the response sampled or measured? How do you model the spatial correlation?

Comment: I identified these groups based on their position...and they have been defined a priori nad I created them. Their creation is independent from the response, but most likely the values of the variable response will depend on which group they belong. The spatial correlation is modelled in a individual-based simulation where I have a lattice in a two-dimensional landscape.